# Football: abandoned matches

Tags: rules, football

I need some help to understand if there's a common rule or at least a set of rules that apply when a match is abandoned.

So as far as I know there could be two scenarios. One is the match is abandoned and then it gets rescheduled and played again from the beginning (minute 0) usually in a different day.

The other scenario is the match is abandoned but the play resumes. Although it may not resume exactly from where it stopped it's likely to resume from the second half (45) if it was abandoned before full time (usually they replay the very same day?).

Questions are, do you know if these rules always apply, if yes to all the main competitions in the world? Also, are you aware of other scenarios/rules?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT:** I think I found also another scenario when a match is abandoned but it doesn't get replayed and the outcome is decided by a board meeting. That's the case of Blackpool vs Huddersfield Town (on 2 May 2015).

> After the match, the Football League announced that there would be no replay of the fixture, and that it would hold a board meeting to decide the outcome.

http://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=d486242d-f049-454e-9747-d9e3df3eaab1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Laws of the Game](http://www.theifab.com/#!/laws/the-duration-of-the-match/chapters/abandoned-match) are both very clear on this and pretty useless at the same time:

> An abandoned match is replayed unless the competition rules or organisers determine otherwise.

However, as you've determined, "competition rules or organisers" usually *do* determine otherwise, so you're going to have to read the rules for the specific competition.

Comment: So anything could happen basically. Doesn't sound ideal but I guess it is what it is. :-)